# How to subscribe the notification from worker threads?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I follow MVC design. I have three Controller parts which runs in main GUI thread. Also have another worker thread which processed some I/O stuffs. Once the worker thread finishes its task, all three controllers should get notification. Can anyone suggest me a solution for this ?

I am using PyQT. So is there any way like; subscribe the events from a worker thread to multiple controller parts ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to just emit a signal in the worker thread. Create three connections from the worker thread's signal to the controllers' slots, and you should be good to go.

Signal/slot connections in Qt are thread-safe and will work as expected. Only the thread in which the object with the slot lives in needs to have an event loop, which is fine, since in your case the slots belong to the controller, which is in the GUI thread which has an event loop.

See the documentation on [QObjects and threads](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/threads-qobject.html) for more details.